# parentOrSelf([selector]) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I use event delegation in lots of my JS scripts. Normally, what I would do is I will have a global event handler, and I would trace to the element that received the event. 
The issue is I cannot *always* use jQuery's filtering selector when installing the event. For example, if you are using it:

```
$('.todo').on('click', function(e) {
  // The event target is guaranteed to be something having the
  // class .todo
  var todo = e.target;
});
```

then it's pretty straightforward,

However, I am now playing with view event delegation in Backbone, and there I can install an event handler:

```
 'click .todo' : 'someHandlerFunction'
```

Problem is in that handler function I am NOT guaranteed to receive the event target at the right, but I can get one of it's descendants instead. That is, I am
getting the event object, but it's target can also be an element inside of something with the ".todo" class, due to bubbling.

Ideally I would like to have a simple function that would do this:

```
 $(document.body).on('click', function(evt) {
   var interestingElementOrNull = jQuery(evt.target).parentOrSelf('.todo');
 });
```

but I have to resort to first doing a `hasClass()` on the event target, and then (if it didn't match) todo the `parent()` call.

Is there a better/standard way to do this?

Comment: can't you just use closest() to get parents or self?  It first checks the current element then upwards in the tree for a match.  Or do you only want to go up one level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wirey says, if you want `ancestorOrSelf()` rather than `parentOrSelf()`, you only have to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var element = jQuery(evt.target).closest(".todo");
```

If you actually want `parentOrSelf()`, you can chain [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) into [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)<sup>*</sup> and apply [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to the result:

```
var element = jQuery(evt.target).parent().addBack().filter(".todo");
```

Note, however, that in both cases, `element` will be an empty jQuery object rather than `null` if nothing is matched. You can test its [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property if you want to determine if something was matched.

<sub>* `addBack()` was named [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) before jQuery 1.8.</sub>

Comment: Yep, what I want is indeed `ancestorOrSelf()`, so `closest()` is what I am looking for. In other news, Backbone should probably filter that for me if I do specify a selector in the events table...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own plugin if you don't want to manually check the event target every time :

```
$.fn.parentOrSelf = function(selector){
    return this.is(selector) ? this : this.closest(selector);
}
```

Comment: `closest()` includes `this` in its search, so you may as well call it directly. (Then again, the semantics of your method are arguably different from `closest()`'s if called on a jQuery object that contains more than one element.)